# plot Roc curve using keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, roc, auc

I have a neural network model and I am using KerasClassifier and then using KFold for cross-validation. Now I am having issues in plotting the ROC curve. I have tried few codes but most of them is giving me an error of multi-labeled is not interpreted. I have the following code till my neural network produces the accuracy. I will be thankful if anyone can help me with the later part of the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
dataset = pd.read_csv('lukemia_2003.csv')
X_train = dataset.values[:,0:12600]
Y_train = dataset.values[:,12600]
scalar = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = scalar.fit_transform(X_train)
pca = PCA(n_components=10)
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(scaled_data)
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y_train)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y_train)
dummy_Y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
hid_layer1 = 4
hid_layer2 = 4
output_layer = 4
def my_model():
    encoded = Sequential()
    encoded.add(Dense(hid_layer1, input_dim = 10, activation='tanh'))
    encoded.add(Dense(hid_layer2, activation='tanh'))
    encoded.add(Dense(output_layer, activation='softmax'))
    encoded.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return encoded

result_mean_list = []
std_list = []
for i in range(30):
    estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=my_model, epochs=1500, batch_size=5, verbose=2)
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train_pca, dummy_Y, cv=kfold)
    result_mean_list.append(round(results.mean()*100,2))
    std_list.append(round(results.std()*100,2))


print ("Result mean: ", result_mean_list)
print ("Standard Deviation List: ", std_list)
```

Here is the link to the dataset. https://drive.google.com/open?id=15emI90-sPZMkHLuwRbNfTBli0h_S-PpM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case since your target is multiclass, you cannot use ROC for the evaluation of the classifier. In a case that there was a binary classifier this [link](https://hackernoon.com/simple-guide-on-how-to-generate-roc-plot-for-keras-classifier-2ecc6c73115a) shows how to draw an ROC curve.

Comment: Yes I have tried this but there is an error showing for the "y_score" variable which is mentioned inside the first for loop. The binary classification ROC-curve in this link works perfectly fine but I have categorical classification where the y_score ends up with an error of "y_score is not defined."

Comment: ROC is a graph for showing the efficiency of binary classifiers(two categories). Your target has 4 categories, so it cannot be used in here. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I only have this dataset which is multiclass classification. other than this the other dataset I have is binary classification for which I am able to achieve the ROC. I am stuck with this multiclass classification. Is there any way of plotting ROC for multi-class

Comment: ROC is meaningless for multi class. It is defined only for binary classification.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). Try confusion matrix for multi class evalution.

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply and guidance. I have one more question. Does ROC curve depends on the neural network model we try to train? or it only depends on the dataset?

Comment: It depends on the quality of the model's prediction. The more it deviates from the 45 degree line, the better is the prediction. Please mark the answer as the right answer if it solved your problem. thanks.

Comment: While your statement sounds logical, people have extended ROC for categorical classifiers as well. In such cases, you have to take a class that you want its ROC as the "positive" label, and the other classes (two/more) as the "negative" labels. And there you go!